# Moving emails to subfolders based on categories

Tags: vba, outlook

My inbox has subfolders which I use to organise/file emails. My folder structure is as follows:

> Inbox
>
> -0day Inbox
>
> -Matters
>
> --1. Topic Name A
>
> ---Client
>
> ----Inbox
>
> ----Sent
>
> ---Internal
>
> ----Inbox
>
> ----Sent
>
> --2. Topic Name B
>
> ---Client
>
> ----Inbox
>
> ----Sent
>
> ---Internal
>
> ----Inbox
>
> ----Sent

The general process I have for filing:

1) All emails received are copied to the "0dayInbox" folder via a rule. This is because I want to leave a copy of all emails in my main Inbox.

2) I go through the 0dayInbox folder and categorize emails based on different topics (e.g. Topic A - Internal or Topic A - Client), or if they are junk emails, mark it to a category called "Not for filing".

3) I have rules to move emails assigned to categories to certain folders, or if marked Not For filing, to permanently delete them. For example, if an email is categorized to Topic A - Internal then it is moved into

**`Inbox --> Matters --> 1. Topic Name A --> Internal --> Inbox folder`**.

4) My Outlook has a timer where every 3 hours it will run the rules over the 0dayInbox folder. Where no category has been assigned the email remains in the 0dayInbox folder.

The above works fine save that whenever I have new topics I have to create new rules. I also don't think the running of the rules is necessarily the most efficient (sometimes I wait a minute or so before it completes).

My code:

In the "ThisOutlookSession" module:

```
Private Sub Application_Quit()
  If TimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Call ActivateTimer(180)
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```
Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerfunc As Long) As Long
Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long

Public Sub ActivateTimer(ByVal nMinutes As Long)
  nMinutes = nMinutes * 1000 * 60 
  If TimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer
  TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, nMinutes, AddressOf TriggerTimer)
  If TimerID = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The timer failed to activate."
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub DeactivateTimer()
Dim lSuccess As Long
  lSuccess = KillTimer(0, TimerID)
  If lSuccess = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The timer failed to deactivate."
  Else
    TimerID = 0
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub TriggerTimer(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idevent As Long, ByVal Systime As Long)

    Dim objRules As Outlook.Rules
    Dim objRule As Outlook.Rule
    Dim olFolder  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("0dayInbox")

    Set objRules = Outlook.Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules

    Set objRule = objRules.Item("Internal-Topic A")
    With objRule
        .Enabled = True
        .Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=olFolder, IncludeSubfolders:=False
    End With

    Set objRule = objRules.Item("Client-Topic A")
    With objRule
        .Enabled = True
        .Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=olFolder, IncludeSubfolders:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

I would like not having to set up a new rule every time I have a new topic; and to do the task more efficiently.

Two alternative options seem to be:

1) Retaining the code as above, but when the timer triggers the routine instead of it running rules, it runs through the 0dayInbox and moves folders based on categories based on a series of If's and Elseif's (or in the case of "Not for filing", permanently deleting them).

2) Removing the timer code and moving emails when they are categorized.

Comment: Get rid of the timer, it slows your Outlook Application. With items events in Outlook  you add categories it auto moves to the correct folder. assuming you are assigning the categories Manually ?

Comment: Thanks - I though that might be the case. Yes assigning the categories manually (although when sending emails I do it at the time of sending rather than after - but that may need to be dealt with separately)